# Laravel user notification feature

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, notifications, queue

I'm trying to implement a notification feature in a Laravel 4 application that I'm building. At the moment there is only one scenario that causes a notification to be posted but it could expand to be multiple. The condition at the moment involves notifying a member of GroupA when a user in GroupB performs an action involving them. For argument's sake, neither GroupA nor GroupB are a finite number of users but GroupB will be larger than GroupA.

My initial reaction was to get the *last_activity* from the session and compare it to the necessary table in the DB to see if there are any items created after that, based on the *created_at* field. This is assuming that Laravel updates *last_activity* at the end of the request instead of the beginning. What I'm having my doubts about is that I'd have to fetch the *last_activity* and then do a lookup on the table for every request that the user in GroupA makes. I don't think that will scale to well.

Secondly, I thought of some sort of queue? Something like beanstalk. If I used beanstalk would it be possible for a user in GroupA to pull all actions that pertain to them (based on user_id) leaving those that aren't for them? Or will I need to implement a separate queue for each user? Is that possible for a group that could potentially be 1000+ users big? Would these queues stay active for an indefinite period allowing notifications to be pushed to them and pulled in by the user when they next login? I've never used queues before, I understand the concept but I'm not sure of the implementation.

Let me know if there's something else I should be doing, haven't implemented something like this before.

Comment: There are 2 ways for notification, push & pull. In case of pull you could send an AJAX request every 5 minutes (more/less) to receive the notifications. Push means that the server pushes the data to the user which will get an instant notification (such as real-time chat). This can be done with Node.js as far as I know. As I think of notifications, I dont think you will need to have real-time so AJAX will do perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attached link may solve your problem :
http://ryantablada.com/post/an-eloquent-notification-strategy